# How to do I reduce/compress the size of a image before uploading to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, compression

I need to know what i would have to do with this code in order to reduce/compress the size of the image being uploaded if a the image being uploaded is over 1mb.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action='upcomg.php' method="post" name="changer">
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="83886080" type="hidden">
<label>Please choose a file:</label><input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
<input value="Submit" type="submit">

<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {

    $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $data = addslashes($data);
    fclose($fp);


    $query = "INSERT INTO ### ";
    $query .= "(##) VALUES ('$data')";
    $results = mysql_query($query, $link);

    // Print results
    print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

    }
    else {
    print "No image selected/uploaded";
    }

    // Close our MySQL Link
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: dont store the image in the db

Answer (score 1):

First off, I wouldn't be storing raw image data in the DB. Storing it in a regular old static file will be much quicker and also won't break if your DB goes offline.

But with that being said, you could just put something like this in there:

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
if ( $_FILES['image']['size'] > 1024*1024 )
    $file = compress($file);
```

Do you have a method of compression already? If not I can help you with that too, but you might want to take a look at [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php) because it already has built in compression.

Comment: could you help me use imagick with this code cuz i have to use databases.

Comment: Just curious, why are you required to store these in a DB? And yes I can help you with Imagick, but first read the documentation and run some test code and let me know if you can't figure it out. Pretty much every PHP framework is very well documented so it should be as simple as reading instructions.

Comment: i hav yo use databases cuz i cant do file upload due to premissions errors like '[function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied'. If u could help me with that, it wil be great.

Comment: So just change the permissions of the upload destination, that's much simpler.

Comment: i tried to but i get an like '500 'SITE CHMOD 777 ver_2': command not understood'

Comment: Please accept my answer and contact me through my website mdl.fm and I will assist you further, because a stack of comments isn't a very efficient means of doing so.